# How to move SVG element with bobril framework

Tags: javascript, svg, typescript, single-page-application, bobril

I want to move an SVG element (circle) with mouse in bobril. Which lifecycle component method should I use? I tried to use `onPointerDown` and so on, but these methods only handle the events inside the circle. Should I use drag and drop or is there some other option to move the circle around the whole SVG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `onPointerDown`, `onPointerMove` and `onPointerUp` component lifecycle methods (more info in [bobril/index.ts](https://github.com/Bobris/Bobril/blob/master/package/index.ts) `IBobrilComponent`) are exactly what you need but with little bit more code.

Use bobril `b.registerMouseOwner` with your context in `onPointerDown` method.

```js
onPointerDown(ctx: ICtx, event: b.IBobrilPointerEvent) {
    b.registerMouseOwner(ctx);

    // Store the initial coordinates
    ctx.lastX = event.x;
    ctx.lastY = event.y;
    return true;
},
```

Then your component can handle mouse move in `onPointerMove` method even moving outside the element. You only have to be sure that you are still the current owner. So your method can look e.g. like this:

```js
onPointerMove(ctx: ICtx, event: b.IBobrilPointerEvent) {
    if (!b.isMouseOwner(ctx))
        return false;

    if (ctx.lastX === event.x && ctx.lastY === event.y)
        return false;

    // Call handler if it is registered
    if (ctx.data.onMove) {
        ctx.data.onMove(event.x - ctx.lastX, event.y - ctx.lastY);
    }

    // Update coordinates 
    ctx.lastX = event.x;
    ctx.lastY = event.y;

    return true;
},
```

Don't forget to release your registration.

```js
onPointerUp(ctx: ICtx, event: b.IBobrilPointerEvent) {
    b.releaseMouseOwner();
    return true;
}
```

The example above stores the last pointer coordinates into the component context `ICtx`. Then it can be used to provide `deltaX` and `deltaY` to `onMove` handler. This handler can be registered by input data when you create the node of the component.

Comment: I would just add to make it multi-touch friendly you should check `event.id` and later ignore all other pointer ids. And to be good listen also on `onPointerCancel` which should rollback all your actions because browser decided so.